# PPA package: Specify different dependencies for different Ubuntu versions

Tags: ppa, dependencies, packaging

Let's say I have a PPA package that depends on the `libtool` executable to build. In Vivid, this executable is provided by the `libtool-bin` package. For earlier Ubuntu versions, it is provided by the `libtool` package.

Using a substitution variable like `${dist:BuildDepends}` is apparently only possible for `Depends`, but not for `Build-Depends`. So how do I specify the `Build-Depends` in the control file of my package to work with both Vivid (`Build-Depends: libtool-bin`) and earlier versions (`Build-Depends: libtool`)?

Comment: If you're checking `lsb-release`, you could get the distribution code and check if it is greater than 14.04.

Comment: @muru: Thanks, I tried that, but substitution variables apparently do not work for `Build-Depends`, only for `Depends`. I updated the question.

Comment: Did you try an OR: `Build-Depends: libtool-bin (>= 2.4.2-1.10) | libtool (< 2.4.2-1.10)`?

Comment: @muru: Nice trick.. let's hope they don't backport a newer libtool version to e.g. utopic. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Since I saw you at vi.SE, you might be interested to know that I used this to build the Neovim PPA at https://code.launchpad.net/~neovim-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/unstable :-)

Comment: Anything I need to know before trying out that PPA?

Comment: @muru: Neovim uses `.nvimrc` and `.nvim/` for configuration. The executable is `nvim`. For Python-based plugins (e.g. YouCompleteMe), you need to `pip install neovim`. The terminal UI has been re-implemented (for the "why", see e.g. [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2034)) a few days ago, so you might encounter some bugs in that area. Other than that, if you have any questions/problems, just post them at https://github.com/neovim/neovim. You can find some links to documentation at http://neovim.org/doc. I have been using Neovim since summer last year, and it works pretty well :-).

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion. I wasn't around, so it got rejected. I made the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case `libtool`/`libtool-bin`, I think an OR relation might work:

```
Build-Depends: libtool-bin (>= 2.4.2-1.10) | libtool (<< 2.4.2-1.10)
```

The version numbers are that of [`utopic`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/libtool), when the split was imported from Debian. Note that in `2.4.2-1.10`, `libtool` still depends on `libtool-bin`. The dependency was reversed in `2.4.2-1.11`, which is why this change is now needed.

Depending on what you do, it might be simpler and safer to add a combined `libtool` to a separate PPA and depend on it. Since this is a B-D, it needn't be installed by your end-users, so depending on a separate PPA should be safe.